# I'm having trouble referencing Checking if an entry in an SQL Table Exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

BY the way, I'm new to VB.NET

I have a form that a user will input information and it will be added to a database (if the entry does not already exist.).

There are 6 columns in the database, which will be filled in by 6 textboxes that the user enters information into, these are First Name, last Name, Home address, City, US State, and Phone Number

```
Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM Salespeople WHERE FirstName=@FirstName AND LastName=@LastName AND HomeAddress=@HomeAddress AND City=@City"
Dim repeatChecker As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(theQuery, myconnection)
repeatChecker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First Name", TextBox1.Text)
        repeatChecker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last Name", TextBox2.Text)
        repeatChecker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Home Address", TextBox10.Text)
        repeatChecker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", TextBox9.Text)
        repeatChecker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@US_State", TextBox11.Text)
        repeatChecker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", TextBox8.Text)
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = repeatChecker.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                ' User already exists
                MsgBox("User Already Exist!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Add New User!")
            End If
        End Using
```

I get the error that there is incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar', and that I must declare the variable @First Name. I have no idea what to change.

Comment: You got a space in your parameter names

Comment: I will just leave this here. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @HugoYates when I take the space out I get 3 sqlexceptions:
Invalid column name 'FirstName'.
Invalid column name 'LastName'.
Invalid column name 'HomeAddress'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your column names have spaces..

```
Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM Salespeople WHERE [First Name]=@FirstName AND [Last Name]=@LastName AND [Home Address]=@HomeAddress AND City=@City"
Dim repeatChecker As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(theQuery, myconnection)
repeatChecker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", TextBox1.Text)
        repeatChecker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", TextBox2.Text)
        repeatChecker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeAddress", TextBox10.Text)
        repeatChecker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", TextBox9.Text)
        repeatChecker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@US_State", TextBox11.Text)
        repeatChecker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", TextBox8.Text)
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = repeatChecker.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                ' User already exists
                MsgBox("User Already Exist!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Add New User!")
            End If
        End Using
```

Comment: I forgot to modify the columns on the first line:
Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM Salespeople WHERE [First Name]=@FirstName AND [Last Name]=@LastName AND [Home Address]=@HomeAddress AND City=@City"

Thank you! It works now.